# Relationship between properties of linear transformations algebraically and visually

Tags: linear-algebra

I learned from [3Blue1Brown's Linear Algebra videos](https://youtu.be/kYB8IZa5AuE?t=2m43s) that a 2-D transformation is linear if it follows these rules:

- lines remain lines without getting curved
- the origin remains fixed in place
- grid lines remain parallel and evenly spaced

I'm now going through linear algebra from a textbook, which lays out this definition of a linear transformation:

- T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)
- T(cu) = cT(u)

I'm wondering, is there a connection between these two ways of thinking of linear transformations? Do the visual ways of seeing 2-D linear transformations correspond to the formal definition when in 2-D?

Comment: I recently asked a question in this spirit with some insightful answers (though I asked in the more abstract setting of vector spaces over arbitrary fields) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035208/is-a-map-that-preserves-lines-and-fixes-the-origin-necessarily-linear

Comment: I've read your question and have to say I don't fully understand it or the answers as I'm just starting out in linear algebra, but thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2):

If we make reasonable algebraic definitions for the three points above, then the answer is yes: there is a correspondence between the geometric perspective and the algebraic perspective.

Let $f$ be a map that fixes the origin ($f(\vec{0}) = \vec{0}$) and sends lines of evenly spaced points to lines of evenly spaced points ($f(\vec{u} + c\vec{v}) = \vec{u}' + c\vec{v}'$). Then we have

$$
f(c\vec{v}) = c\vec{v}'
$$

If we take $c=1$ then we get $f(\vec{v}) = \vec{v}'$. So $f(c\vec{v}) = cf(\vec{v})$.

Now consider

$$
f(c_1\vec{u} + c_2\vec{v}) = \vec{u}' + c_2\vec{v}'
$$

If we set $c_2 = 0$, we get

$$
f(c_1\vec{u}) = c_1 f(\vec{u}) = \vec{u}'
$$

So we have

$$
f(c_1 \vec{u} + c_2 \vec{v}) = c_1f(\vec{u}) +c_2\vec{v}'
$$

But if $c_1 = 0$, we then have

$$
f(c_2 \vec{v}) = c_2 f(\vec{v}) = c_2 \vec{v}'
$$

So $f(c_1 \vec{u} + c_2 \vec{v}) = c_1 f(\vec{u}) + c_2f(\vec{v})$. So $f$ is linear. Therefore, if $f$ fixes the origin and sends lines of evenly spaced points to evenly spaced points, then $f$ is linear.

Can you show the converse ?

Comment: Ok, I think the key insight for me is where you say $f(\vec{u} + c\vec{v}) = \vec{u}' + c\vec{v}'$. Is it correct that this is the mathematical way of saying that f sends lines of evenly spaced points to lines of evenly spaced points because they are moved apart by a constant c?

Comment: I thought of $\vec u + c \vec v$ as a line that touches the point $\vec u$ oriented in the direction $\vec v$ since we are adding multiples of $\vec v$ to $\vec u$. So if $\vec u' + c \vec v'$ is parallel then $\vec v'$ needs to be a multiple of $\vec v$ right? I don't see why $f(c\vec{v}) = c\vec{v}'$ needs to be true.

Comment: @Aditya A linear transformation sends a collection of parallel lines in the input space to a collection of parallel lines in the output space. Note the lines in the input space need *not* to be parallel _to the lines in the output space_. $f(c\vec{v})=c\vec{v}’$ must be true because $f$ must send an equally spaced set of points along the line spanned by $\vec{v}$ to an equally spaced set of points spanned by another line, which we define to be $\vec{v}’$

Comment: Now that you point it out, it's laughable that I was thinking v was parallel to v'. One is in input space, the other in output space. Ok so I think I get you, you are considering the set of all equally spaced points that lie on a line, that would be line itself. Since the line oriented along v passing through u becomes a line oriented along v' and passing through u'. Here you just take u to be the zero vector and then that is true.