# Mapping subspaces of dimension $2$ to subspaces of dimension $2$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, functions, vector-spaces

**Setting.** Let $V$ be a vector space over some field $F$ with $\dim(V) \geq 3$. A map $\phi : V \to V$ is called *flat* if the image of any subspace of dimension $2$ is again a subspace of dimension $2$.

**Question.** Is the implication
$$f \text{ flat} \implies f \text{ injective}$$
always true?

**Motivation.** In the case of a finite field $F = \mathbb F_q$, the answer is "yes": Assume that $\phi(v) = \phi(w)$ for two distinct vectors $v,w\in V$. Let $U$ be a subspace of dimension $2$ containing $v$ and $w$. Then $\#U = q^2$, but $\#\phi(U) \leq q^2 - 1$, which is a contradiction.

**Clarifications.**

1. The map $\phi$ is **not** assumed to be linear! (For linear maps $\phi$, it is not hard to see that the answer is "yes".)
2. The term "subspace" means "vector subspace" (and not "affine subspace").

Comment: This seems to be related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035208/is-a-map-that-preserves-lines-and-fixes-the-origin-necessarily-linear also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985327/is-lines-remain-lines-sufficient-to-characterise-linearity-in-mathbb-r2

Comment: Possibly https://mathoverflow.net/questions/163923/properties-of-vector-spaces-without-ac is related.

Comment: Concerning the 2 links to MSE: of course, I immediately thought of this "[fundamental theorem of affine geometry](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9or%C3%A8me_fondamental_de_la_g%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie_affine)". But the difficulty lies in proving that if planes remain planes then lines remain lines. As for the link to MO: I cannot see how it could be related.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Many thanks for your pointers. Yes, there is some relation to your first pair of links, in the sense that they explore the outskirts of the fundamental theorem of projective geometry (the one which states that every collineation of a projective Desarguesian geometry of dimension $\geq 2$ is induced by a semilinear map). But I don't see how they should help making progress here. Concerning the mathoverflow-Link: Admittedly, that one is a bit scary to me :) But yes, maybe it is related. I'd not be too surprised if in the end, the property depends on the axiom of choice...

Comment: Right, I humbly retract my comment. +1 for the interesting question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm not sure I see how the MO post is related. The words flat and injective mean completely different things in that question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming subspace means vector subspace and not affine subspace, and with $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$, take some $v \ne 0$, map $kv$ for $k \in [2, \infty)$ to $(k - 1) v$ and map everything else by identity. Then the image of every line is itself, so the image of every plane is itself.

Comment: thank you! I think your are right. Seems that I was thinking too complicated...

Comment: What goes wrong with assuming affine subspace?

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Consider an affine plane through $2v$ which does not contain the origin. This particular map will take such a plane to a punctured plane and an isolated point.