# If image of every line is a line, is that transform linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

$F$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. For every line $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $F(L)$ is a line, too. Also it maps origin to origin. Then, is $F$ a linear transform?

Comment: [3blue1brown's video](https://youtu.be/kYB8IZa5AuE) on the topic might enlighten you.

Comment: think about a reflection in $\mathbb{R}^2$, is it linear?

Comment: No. Consider a translation.

Comment: Do you consider translation a linear transform?

Comment: I changed the question. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Arthur: great piece of advice! Also, I think this is a very good question, but it should show some more effort to be upvoted.

Comment: Various forms of this question were discussed a number of times on MSE, see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035287/is-a-function-which-preserves-zero-and-affine-lines-necessarily-linear?noredirect=1&lq=1) and  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035208/is-a-map-that-preserves-lines-and-fixes-the-origin-necessarily-linear?noredirect=1&lq=1), and in the linked questions.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collineation